# How to access azure DEVOPS library variables in PHP? It is possible?

Tags: php, laravel, azure, devops

Due to company restrictions, I'm not allowed to get IDClient, secretKey to access an API on azure. Variables were then created in DEVOPS for me to access. How to access these DEVOPS variables in PHP? Thanks.

[image: imageExample]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by DEVOPS variables, you mean environment variables were created, then you would be able to access them using `$_ENV['VARIABLE_NAME']`

Comment: Hi, I put an image to illustrate. tks.